# prerender.io not working with expressjs and angularjs

Tags: node.js, angularjs, prerender

I have setup a server with Express.js:

```
const env = process.env.ENV || 'PROD';
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

if(env === 'PROD') {
    app.all('*', function(req, res, next) {
        var protocol = req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'];
        if(protocol && protocol === 'http') {
            res.redirect(301, 'https://' + req.headers.host + req.url);
        }
        return next();
    });
}

app.use(require('prerender-node').set('prerenderToken', 'mytoken'));

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/app/'));

app.get('*', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/app/index.html');
});

app.listen(port);
console.log("App started on port "+port);
```

In angularjs app set config:

```
config(['$locationProvider', '$routeProvider', function ($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}])
```

In index.html:

```
<meta name="fragment" content="!">
```

As documentation says:
https://prerender.io/documentation/test-it

I do:

http://mydomainm/user/1?_escaped_fragment_=

But my page not cached.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it looks like the middleware is working properly but you are sending us an http URL so we are returning a 301. Can you modify your middleware to be like this:

```
app.use(require('prerender-node').set('prerenderToken', 'mytoken').set('protocol', 'https'));
```

That should fix that redirect issue and get everything working properly.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like it should be working properly. Can you send an email to support@prerender.io so that we can check your Crawl Stats and do some testing on our end? Thanks!